# Converting python2 library to python3

Tags: django, pip, python-3.5

I have installed django-socketio using pip in my windows machine. Later I realized it has written in python2. I removed the package using the command

```
pip uninstall django-socketio
```

Then I downloaded the source code from [here](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio) and refactored for python3 and installed it using the command

```
python setup.py install
```

but my example code still referring the python2 version code from somewhere.
I haven't create any virtual environment. Any suggestions about what I have done wrong. Here is a part of my stacktrace..

```
...
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 759, in source_to_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "../..\django_socketio\management\commands\runserver_socketio.py", line 57
print "SocketIOServer running on %s:%s" % bind
                                      ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

If there is a way to find `django-websocktio` for `python3` or good suggestion will be much helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, there are different versions of pip (one for each python version).

Try `C:/path/to/python3 -m virtualenv .venv` and then `.venv/scripts/activate.ps1`  after which you'll be in a python3 [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/).

Invoking pip from here should install the right version of django-socketio.

Type `deactivate` to exit the virtual environment.